# How can any user invoke "yum info jdk" and have it work?

Tags: yum, jdk

I am using CentOS 7.2.  I installed JDK.  When I run `yum info jdk` I see everything I expect to see.  For some background, I used a `yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="myrepo" install jdk` to get jdk to be installed.

The problem I have is when a web-based program that installs an application, I get an error.  This web-based application is not a multi-tiered system. I operate the web UI that is completely hosted on this same Linux server runs `yum info jdk`, it cannot retrieve the data.  I see in the logs "time out" errors associated with repos that do not appear to be "myrepo."  I do not know if the web UI is having a different result because other OS users are presumably involved.  Other repos are tried, but not "myrepo" that is local to my network.  How can any user run `yum info jdk` and get the results I see when I run it from the backend as a sudo user?  I would expect each user to have the same results from `yum info jdk`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem. When you say "any user", you mean "the user account the web server runs as, in that context", right?

Comment: And, when your web application runs a command, is it _after_ jdk is installed? Do you _want_ it to contact a repo, or get information about the already-locally-installed package?

Comment: What operating system is this on? Fedora, CentOS, RHEL, other? And, what version?

Comment: I do not know what true underlying user that runs the Linux OS commands that are initiated from the web server application. Does that answer the first comment?  The web app runs after JDK is installed.  I want the "yum info jdk" command to work and not time out with successive failed attempts at contacting different repos.  I wish the "yum info jdk" did not have to run.  I do not know the point.  It can run manually from the back end when I try it.  For some reason the app stops processing if "yum info jdk" does not return correct info.

Comment: My first question is: you say "any user", but do you really mean "any user", or do you mean _that user in specific_?

Comment: My _new_ question is: When you say "the app stops processing", what exactly does that mean? What is it processing, and what does it look like when it stops? When you say that it stops if `yum info jdk` does not return "correct info", do you mean it somehow is _examining_ that output and looking for something? How is it doing that?

Comment: It _seems_ like you are expecting the literal command `yum info jdk` to contact your "myrepo" and not any others even though you are not providing it with the `--disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="myrepo"` flags. Is that correct?

Comment: I do not mean any user.  I just mean the user that is calling the "yum info jdk".  The web UI shows progress.  It stops every time when it gets to a step that says "installing JDK."  JDK was been installed.  The "details" of the failure/stop show the results of the "yum info jdk" command.  The results show that it had many timeouts with different repos that were attempted to be connected to.  I am expecting yum info jdk to connect to myrepo.  The web UI won't let me provide the --disablerepo and --enablerepo flags.  I thought yum commands tried multiple repos until it found a match.

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: If jdk is installed, `yum info` won't need to connect to _any_ repo to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, or why you need to run yum from your web application. This seems... dodgy. However, I suspect that all you need is to run

```
yum -C info jdk
```

because the `-C` flag tells `yum` to run only from cache — or other local resources — and to not contact the network, which it won't need to do for info on an installed package. With `info` for an installed package, as you say `jdk` is, this will work even if there isn't a yum metadata cache, because it will get the info from the `rpm` database.

Comment: Will this apply to other users?  I'm concerned that it will stand for one session on the back end.  But I think it may not apply to the web UI initiated session.

Comment: I think you have a basic misconception — the command line flags apply to _that invocation of yum_. They do not change configuration.

Comment: A script that the web UI invokes clears the yum cache.  I'm sure your solution could have been beneficial otherwise.  It will not work for me given my specific circumstances.

Comment: See edit. `yum info` does not actually need the yum cache.